# OneDrive suddenly stopped syncing

Tags: sync, cloud

I have a dual boot with Windows. I installed OneDrive and it worked well. Now it doesn't sync anymore. Do you have any suggestions?

```
journalctl --user-unit onedrive -f
-- Logs begin at ג' 2018-04-03 12:46:32 IDT. --
אפר 03 09:50:30 Tsachi-Linux onedrive[1623]: src/main.d:190 void main.performSync(sync.SyncEngine) [0x5691c7]
אפר 03 09:50:30 Tsachi-Linux onedrive[1623]: src/main.d:166 _Dmain [0x568e64]
אפר 03 09:50:30 Tsachi-Linux onedrive[1623]: HTTP request returned status code 400 (Bad Request)
אפר 03 09:50:30 Tsachi-Linux onedrive[1623]: {
אפר 03 09:50:30 Tsachi-Linux onedrive[1623]:     "error": "invalid_grant",
אפר 03 09:50:30 Tsachi-Linux onedrive[1623]:     "error_codes": [
אפר 03 09:50:30 Tsachi-Linux systemd[1619]: onedrive.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
אפר 03 09:50:30 Tsachi-Linux systemd[1619]: onedrive.service: Unit entered failed state.
אפר 03 09:50:30 Tsachi-Linux systemd[1619]: onedrive.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sync"

Comment: Make sure you have enough space in your one drive free accounts can increase and decrease in allotted space based on a number of things.

Answer (score 2):

> I installed OneDrive and it worked well. Now it doesn't sync anymore. Do you have any suggestions?

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

This issue was specifically caused by a change in OneDrive authentication.

To fix the issue, you need to use the correct 'onedrive' client version for your platform. Refer to https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md for details on how to install for Ubuntu.